# What does I/O/T stand for in a pinout diagram? (ESP32-S2)

Tags: microcontroller, pinout, esp32

I am looking at the pinout of an ESP32-S2 board with LCD (see picture below) and I am wondering what I/O/T stands for. I am particularly looking at pin IO46 and wondering if it can be used only as input (in case the "I" stands for input):

[image: The pinout diagram]

Comment: I: input; O: output; T: high impedance.

Comment: What does the manual say what it means?

Comment: refer to the datasheet for pin usage

Comment: [Don't ask the same question on two Stack Exchange sites please](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/81709/what-does-i-o-t-stand-for-in-a-pinout-diagram-esp32-s2)

Comment: @StarCat, ok sorry

Comment: And thanks, I'm very new to electronics, I will get into the habit of finding and reading data sheets.

Comment: Input Output Tristate, nevertheless, this is the kind of question google is good for

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the comments:
I=Input
O=Output
T=Tristate (high impedance)

This information is available in "Appendix A.1. Notes on ESP32 Pin Lists" in the ESP32 datasheet.

Comment: Thanks, page 41, link here: https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32-s2_datasheet_en.pdf